# One Nginx, 2 apps/domains

Tags: nginx

I have 2 Rails apps running on the same server. I want requests to domain1.com to get forwarded to my Rails1 app, and the domain2.com requests to my Rails2 app. I configured my nginx.conf like so:

```
upstream thin1 {
    server 0.0.0.0:3000;
    server 0.0.0.0:3001;
    server 0.0.0.0:3002;
}

upstream thin2 {
    server 0.0.0.0:3003;
    server 0.0.0.0:3004;
    server 0.0.0.0:3005;
}

server {
    listen          80;
    server_name     *.domain1.com;
    root            /path1/;        

    location / {
        try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @backend;
    }

    location @backend {
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://thin1;
    }   
}

server {
    listen                  80;
    server_name             *.domain2.com;
    root                    /path2/;

    location / {
        try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @backend;
    }

    location @backend {
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://thin2;
    }   
}
```

But all requests (domain1.com and domain2.com) get forwarded to my Rails1 app. Any idea?

Comment: upstream thin1 and thin2 have the same server address? Are you sure it's correct?

Comment: @freestyler oops, fixed that. The ports are different. Does that make sense?

Comment: Are you sure the \@backend named location isn't shared between servers? Splitting the file in 2 might help. Or try use \@backend1, \@backend2 as named locations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using 2 different names for your named locations should fix it:

```
location @backend1 {
  proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_redirect off;
  proxy_pass http://thin1;
}

location @backend2 {
  proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_redirect off;
  proxy_pass http://thin2;
}
```

(don't forget to change the try_files directive of each server accordingly)

Answer (score 0):

Setup a separate server config for each hostname and forward to the appropriate backends for each host.

Comment: Mind sharing some code? That's pretty much what my config file does right now. I don't see how splitting it into 2 different files would make a difference...